# Multi-column div with vertical scroll

Tags: html, css

I currently am struggling with a problem I thought would be simple:

- I want to split the content of a `div` in two columns
- I need the first column to fill the container's height, and the second column to overflow vertically
- I need that when you scroll down, the top content of the second column appears at the bottom of the first column

So far, I tried to use the `column-count` feature, but if I set `height: 100%`, then it adds columns on the right (with a horizontal scroll), and if I don't, then the content continues on the first column, so you have to scroll down to finish reading first column, before you go read the second column...

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.cols {
  height: 100%;
  column-count: 2;
  column-fill: auto;
}

.cols-2 {
  column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="cols">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="cols-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to do this with css/html only?

Here is how I want it to look like (before/during/after scrolling):

[image: Target]

Comment: Can you explain this more concisely using an image/diagram?

Comment: _"I need that when you scroll down, the top content of the second column appears at the bottom of the first column"_ - I don't think CSS provides any native way to achieve _that_. This probably can't be achieved without duplicating the content, and involving some JavaScript.

Comment: @QuantumX I added expected behaviour as images

Comment: And how do you expect it to behave at the very end of scrolling? Do you want to to be able to scroll so far, that the content of column #2 completely disappears, and the content of column #1 will be flush with the bottom border of the container? Or the other way around - col #2 will be flush with the bottom of the container, and the excess of col #1 will get "cut off" at that point?

Comment: @CBroe at the very end of scrolling, I want that the content ends at the bottom of column #2. Say in my image example (on the right), the content ends at "nostrud", and we are at the end of scrolling, this is how I want it to look like

Comment: The third part of your requirement isn't easily solvable with CSS. Not using CSS `columns`, and by cloning the content, you can do something like this, https://jsfiddle.net/4h1507bL/ (I increased the width to 200px, because some of the longer words in your lorem ipsum text did not fit into 150px to begin with.) You'll notice that the tops of the first lines do not exactly line up - you'll have to fiddle with the line-height, and/or make a bit of a "magic number" adjustment to the negative margin-top value. [...]

Comment: [...] And I did not find a way to get the first column to get "cut off" at the correct point - so for that, you'll likely have to involve a bit of JavaScript (which you probably want to do for the "cloning" part to begin with), to calculate the correct height.

Comment: @CBroe I really was looking for a solution **not** involving **cloning** content, as the real content is going to be a form, and not some dummy text, so cloning form inputs isn't really an option here

Comment: Eww, sticking a form into that, sounds like a usability nightmare already :-) But I don't see much of a different way, than by using a clone. I mean, sure, you could chop your form content up into elements that contain a "single line" (however much that will actually be), and then instead of _actually_ scrolling the content, fake that using JavaScript - and then start setting elements from the beginning to `display: none`, so that following elements will move from column 2 to column 1 then. But that will be rather "jumpy" than smooth then.

Comment: Plus, even simple stuff I as a user  expect to just _work_ in any form, such as going to the previous input field using [shift]+[tab], will probably become difficult to implement then, when that input field is already hidden.

Comment: @CBroe And this is why I would have expected a css thing like `columns-count` to have an option for this behaviour that would allow a user to smoothly scroll across two columns in a single container ;)

Answer (score 1):

This happens because **columns** grow **horizontally**. You set the `columns-count: 2;` but forgot to set `column-width`.

| **Note**: Make sure that you do not make the **width** too small. otherwise some words with long *char* will hide because of `overflow-x: hidden;` but if you add `word-break: break-all;` then it will fixed all the word into your given **width**.

here is code:

```css
.container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.cols {
/*   word-break: break-all; */
  column-count: 2;
  columns-width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="cols">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</div>
```

Hope you have got your answer. if not, tell me.

Comment: This doesn't fulfill the third requirement that was given, at all: _"I need that when you scroll down, the top content of the second column appears at the bottom of the first column"_

Comment: @CBroe This is not possible with **HTML/CSS** only.

Comment: You don't have to tell me, because that's what I said in comments an hour ago already :-) But all that leaves us with here is an "answer", that does not actually answer the question.

Comment: Indeed, this is what I already got when I didn't set an height: "*if I don't, then the content continues on the first column, so you have to scroll down to finish reading first column, before you go read the second column*" (quote from my own question)